# java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I tried searching the forum for this error but could find one which answered my query.
I am facing an error when i try to migrate from spring-hibernate xml to spring-hibernate annotation. The error is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:901)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1190)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5279)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

my dispatcher servlet looks like the below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx

http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<!--<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />-->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vaannila" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />



<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/seed"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.vaannila.domain.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--<bean id="myUserDAO" class="com.vaannila.dao.UserDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean name="/user/*.htm" class="com.vaannila.web.UserController" >
    <property name="userDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
</bean>-->

    <bean id="transactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Can anyone here please help me ASAP?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class
>   specified on bean definition

You need to specify the transaction manager class here

```
<bean id="transactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

may be you need this class

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"">
          <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error log tells you clearly. You specified ID of the bean (instance) without specifying which class it should instantiate.